# How to "see" the structure of an object in python

Tags: python, object, introspection, tweepy

I am wokring in python 2.7.  I have been experimenting with the [tweepy](http://tweepy.github.com/) package.  There is an object called the tweepy.models.status object, whose function is defined here: https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/blob/master/tweepy/models.py.

I have a function that looks like this:

```
    def on_status(self, status):
        try:
            print status
            return True
        except Exception, e:
            print >> sys.stderr, 'Encountered Exception:', e
            pass
```

The object I am referring to is the one returned from the `on_status` function, called `status`.  When the `print status` line executes i get this printed on the screen;

> tweepy.models.Status object at 0x85d32ec>

My question is actually pretty generic.  I want to know how to visually print out the contents of this `status` object? I want to know what information is available inside this object.

I tried the `for i, v in status :` approach, but it says this objects is not iterable.  Also not all of the object attributes are described in the function definition.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: +1'd and favourited. I've generally just used `dir` but now the answer from mgilson gives me something more concrete to re-use. Wanted to add: Dive Into Python (for v2, first one) has a chapter on [introspection with an `apihelper`->`info` function](http://www.diveintopython.net/power_of_introspection/index.html). Also gives some useful info about members, etc. and documentation from the doc strings.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could iterate over `status.__dict__.items()`:

```
for k,v in status.__dict__.items():  #same thing as `vars(status)`
    print k,v
```

The above approach won't work if the class uses `__slots__` and doesn't have a slot for `__dict__`.  Classes with `__slots__` are quite rare though, so it's unlikely to be a problem.

Alternatively, you could use the [`dir` builtin](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#dir) with `getattr`:

```
for attr in dir(status):
    print attr, getattr(status,attr)
```

This does work for classes with `__slots__`, but has some limitations if a custom `__getattr__` is defined (see link, and `__dict__` would suffer in the same way).

Finally, if you want really fine control over what you see (e.g. if you only want methods), you can check out some of the goodies in the [`inspect` module](http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html).

Comment: So I tried your first suggestions and get this error: `Encountered Exception: too many values to unpack` ... seems like some huge data.

Comment: The second suggestion worked well! `for attr in dir(status)`.  Thanks!

Comment: @jeffery_the_wind -- Sorry about the first one.  (ProgrammerError on my part).  `status.__dict__` is the dictionary.  To iterate over key/value pairs in a dictionary you need it's `items` method.  Updated.

Comment: @deadly -- what mistake?  *\*whistles innocently\**

Answer (score 6):

I've always been a fan of the `dir` builtin for manual introspection.  Works on modules, objects...

```
>>> import math
>>> dir(math)
['__doc__', '__name__', '__package__', 'acos', 'acosh', 'asin', 'asinh', 'atan',
 'atan2', 'atanh', 'ceil', 'copysign', 'cos', 'cosh', 'degrees', 'e', 'erf',
 'erfc', 'exp', 'expm1', 'fabs', 'factorial', 'floor', 'fmod', 'frexp', 'fsum',
 'gamma', 'hypot', 'isinf', 'isnan', 'ldexp', 'lgamma', 'log', 'log10', 'log1p',
 'modf', 'pi', 'pow', 'radians', 'sin', 'sinh', 'sqrt', 'tan', 'tanh', 'trunc']
```

I believe it's equivalent to `sorted(`*object*`.__dict__.keys())`.